# Android:textwatcher is swapping keypad automatically from numeric to qwerty after single entry of digit?

Tags: android

I want to use a text watcher which should take both alpha numeric characters and only numeric characters, initially my keypad is qwerty but when I want to enter all numeric values and press a numeric digit my keypad automatically swaps to qwerty back again. Why is this happening? Can you please help me on this?

Comment: what input method your passing in xml file for edittext box.

Comment: android:inputType="text"

Answer (score 0):

if u want to enter only numeric Values change Your Editext inputMethod to like this

```
 android:inputType="phone"
```

and u want to display qwerty Keyboard change it into

```
android:inputType="text"
```

and again if u r facing same problem means u need to change the InputMethod to **AndroidKeyboard** in your Phone Settings.

else add code in **onTextChanged**method

```
@Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {
        editextobj.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
    }
```

Comment: changing inputmethod to AndroidKeyboard is not working instead Swype keypad is working. but i dont want to use swype keypad.

Comment: k what input u need to pass here numbers or both chars

Comment: my edittext should take this format "12345-1234" and "a1b2c3", when i try "123456-1234" this keypad swap issue comes.